# Lotusscript: Change width of Messagebox

Tags: formatting, string-formatting, messagebox, lotusscript

Short and easy:
Is there a possibility to adjust the width of a Messagebox? I couldn't find any info about that in the documentation.
My Messagebox uses only about 50% of the available screen width. But I would need this space in order to have a proper formatting.

Furthermore is there a possibility to display some of the worlds in bold text?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no real control over messageBox except that you can add lines to your message forcing the dialog to be higher, even that and the width can be overridden by the operating system, leading to truncation, although I don't think it does that anymore.

If you want to display a form based dialog box I recommend looking into [@DialogBox](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DIALOGBOX.html), or [DialogBox](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DIALOGBOX_METHOD.html) method in the NotesUIWorkspace class.

Here are [more details on creating these properly](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DESIGNING_A_FORM_THAT_PRESENTS_A_DIALOG_BOX.html).

Comment: Sounds promising!
I managed to display a document with the DialogBox method. But I simply want to display a given string. I could not figure out, how to handle this.

Comment: You would have to create a temporary document using a form that displays the string.  I don't think you have to save the document, though.

Comment: That's it. Thank you! You can find my used code in my own answer below

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Simon O'Doherty here's the code, that worked for me:

First of all I creaded a Form `(DialogBox)` containing a single text field named `DIALOG_BOX_MESSAGE`

```
Set doc=db.CreateDocument
doc.Form="(DialogBox)"
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("DIALOG_BOX_MESSAGE", "My fancy message, to be displayed")
Call ws.DialogBox("(DialogBox)", True, True, True, False, False, True, "Got a fancy title", doc)
```